# selecting element which refer to other elements in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to build a very simple CMS. For that I have create a table called categories. As the name suggests it will be the categories for my articles in the CMS.

My table looks like follows with the sample data: 
[image: table with sample data]

As you can see, a category node has a parent node. now, **How can I write a query which selects all the parent nodes of a particular node.** Example, if I choose, the node **Important**, how can I write a query which will return me the following nodes: **News, Users, General**

I hope I was clear enough

Comment: Have a look: **http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/**

Comment: @PM77-1 Thanks for linking me to that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say that I really love this method, but the following appears to work in MySQL:

```
select t.id, t.parent, @parent := parent
from (select @parent := 7) const join
     t
     on t.id = @parent;
```

You can see it in this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60f9e/1).

I don't believe this is *guaranteed* to work, but it seems to work in practice.  If you need to store hierarchical data, you should really change the data structure or switch to a database that supports recursive queries (Postgres, SQL Server, and Oracle, for instance).

Comment: ah well, it does seem to work! +1 for calling it recursive query and describing it as hierarchical data as I had no clue what to call it when naming the question :P